# Get DKMS offline?

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management

Recently got a laptop with a realtek wifi card.
I got the drivers for it, but it requires dkms to install. Getting the deb package for dkms itself is easy enough, but it requires a ton of dependencies I don't have installed and frankly do not wan to hunt down and install each manually.

Is there some way I can download a version of dkms with all its dependencies?
For all intents and purposes, I cannot connect this machine to the internet for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have not removed any important packages since you installed Ubuntu, so that the set of packages required to install dkms on your computer are the same set of packages required to install dkms in the Live Environment.

1. On a computer that has Internet access, boot into a Live ISO.
2. Open a terminal and execute the following to download the required packages for dkms.

   (Although the gcc package files should also automatically be fetched, I explicitly listed gcc in the `apt` download command below, just to be sure to get all required dependencies).

   ```
    # Remove the CD rom from your sources list so all packages are downloaded.
    sudo sed -i "s|^deb cdrom|# deb cdrom|g" /etc/apt/sources.list

    # Add the universe repository (this will also do an apt update).
    sudo apt-add-repository universe

    # Download packages and dependencies.
    mkdir ~/Downloads/packages
    cd ~/Downloads/packages
    sudo apt --yes --download-only -o Dir::Cache::archives="./" install gcc dkms

    # Change the file permissions so you can work with them.
    sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu *
   ```
3. Copy the above `packages` directory to a USB stick.
4. Plug the USB stick into your target computer (without Internet access).
5. Copy the `packages` directory from USB stick into your `~/Downloads` directory on your target computer.
6. Open a terminal and execute the following:

   ```
    cd ~/Downloads/packages

    sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

Comment: This worked! Posting from the machine I just got working! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this

1. copy DKMS to USB.
2. sneakernet to target.
3. `sudo dpkg -i *`, saving the errors (dependencies).
4. sneakernet back to online system.
5. download dependecies to the same USB.
6. back to step 2.

As I recall, I only had to go around the steps 2-6 3 or 4 times. It's not an infinite loop.

In my case "sneakernet" was just up/down 1 flight of stairs, YMMV.