# How do I download RTL8821CE dependencies, install on main machine and install the driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

I purchased my new laptop a few days ago and currently I am setting everything up, I already have Ubuntu 20.04 running but I need to install the network driver for the RTL8821CE. I don’t have an ethernet port on my laptop. Is there A way I am able to download bc, build-essential, dkms and module-assistant and all its dependencies as .deb files and then install the prebuilt driver?

Comment: Do you have a smartphone you can use USB tethering with? It might make it easier, because you can just connect your system straight to the Internet through your phone.

Comment: Only just to install the driver from the repositories, so you can use the Wi-Fi driver when built from then on.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use USB tethering on a smartphone or some other method of connecting to the Internet, use your tethering to install `rtl8821ce-dkms` via `apt`, which will build the driver automatically. You simply reboot once installation complete, and you have Wi-Fi available.

Otherwise, you need to download `dkms` and your `rtl8821ce-dkms` packages to another machine running the *same* Ubuntu live system which does have an Internet connection, and install them manually. It's important to use the same live system as the one you installed Ubuntu with: this is because it will fetch the correct header package for the installed kernel as needed by DKMS.

Follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1331933/287379), but when you get to the line `sudo apt --yes --download-only -o Dir::Cache::archives="./" install gcc dkms`, you need to add `rtl8821ce-dkms` to it to also download the DKMS sources for your driver.

Comment: I suspect that `build-essential` which includes gcc is needed here.

Comment: @chili555 I would have assumed `dkms` would depend on `gcc`, `make` and so forth in any case. It’s just that it is the command mentioned in the linked guide.